# Google Apps Email Settings API and oauth2.0 Credential with service account

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth, google-api, google-apps

I'm trying to use Oauth 2.0 Google Credential with service account in java to edit user signature but i receive that error:

```
com.google.gdata.util.ServiceForbiddenException: OK
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>You are not authorized to access this API.</TITLE></HEAD><BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000"><H1>You are not authorized to access this API.</H1><H2>Error 403</H2></BODY></HTML>
```

I have created a piece of code to use GoogleCredential object with service account email in this mode:

```
  HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
  JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
  Collection<String> clist= new ArrayList<String>(
            Arrays.asList("https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/",                    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user" 
                    ));
  GoogleCredential gc=null;
try {
    gc = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
      .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
      .setServiceAccountId(c.getServiceAccountEmail())
      .setServiceAccountScopes(clist)
      .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new java.io.File(c.getPkcs12FileName()))
      .build();
} catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
  this.setOAuth2Credentials(gc);
```

I have inserted the scopes in the domain Google Apps for Business panel for the service account and in the console project i have enabled Admin sdk API.

Why i receive that i'm not authorized?
I'm allowed to use Oauth 2.0 instead of unsername and password of the admin like in this code?

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#manage_signature_settings

Why there isn't an official gmail settings service that is not a appsforyoudomainservice used for sample?Oauth 2.0 with service account it's supported?

Thank you

Comment: a service account will only allow you to access the account of the service account. I don't understand why you would want to let everyone change your email signature.  Are you sure you shouldn't be using a normal Oauth2 flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've granted the service account rights to act on behalf of your users. Now the service account needs to act as a user in your domain with rights to perform signature updates for all users, in other words, it needs to act as a super admin. Try adding:

.setServiceAccountUser(userEmail)

where userEmail is the email address of a super admin within your Google Apps instance. A [good walkthrough for this is in the Admin SDK documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#instantiate_an_admin_sdk_directory_service_object).

Comment: I had the impression that setServiceAccountUser was (also in the past) used to insert the user that do you want to impersonate in your domain and not an admin email. See there. https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2#Service_Accounts. If i need to put an admin account  i still need to find at least the user super admin un the google apps domain that can change. I can't put directly a string of the admin account.

Comment: Strange. I am pretty sure, that it was working for users which were not super admins. Now, I have to provide super admin account as ServiceAccountUser if I want to list delegates for any user in domain.